# Rounded Corner single Dropdown menu with Hover functionality

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm new to jquery & javascript.. I need to create a drop-down with rounded corner that will work based on hover as shown below..

[image]

Comment: "Hey I need to make a house for a client, could you please build it for me? For free?"

Answer (score 0):

Give border-radius on the hover event

Using CSS

```
select:hover {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* For safari */
    -moz-border-radius: 10px; /* For mozilla */
}
```

Here is an example using jQuery Snippet

```
$("select").hover(function() {
    $(this).css("borderRadius",10px);
});
```

Comment: Why can't you do `select:hover` via CSS?

Comment: @Blender, I thought I showed both ways. Wait let me update :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/mk62n/1/

this is called `border-radius` property in CSS.

```
-webkit-border-radius:4px;
-moz-border-radius:4px;
-o-border-radius:4px;
border-radius:4px;
```